# Python 2.7 - Pygame - move_ip() too granular

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I'm practicing making an android app in pygame, and decided to do your classic bubble shooter. I have run into a problem though where the projectile launched by the player isn't accurate enough.

```
def move (self, time_passed):

    x = (math.sin(self.angle) * self.speed) * time_passed
    y = (math.cos(self.angle) * self.speed) * time_passed
    c = self.rect.center
    self.rect.center = (c[0]+x, c[1]+y)

def update(self, screen, time_passed):

    if self.launched:
        if not self.mpos:
            self.mpos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            diffx, diffy = (self.mpos[0]-self.rect.center[0],
                            self.mpos[1]-self.rect.center[1])
            self.angle = math.atan2(diffx, diffy)
        self.move(time_passed)
```

The `screen` and `time_passed` arguments are passed from the main loop and are the display and returned value of the Clock class's `tick(60)/1000.0`, for the sake of clarity.

If I print the values of x and y from `move()` it's very accurate: `x: 1.0017224084 y: -21.9771825359`, or something similar depending on where the mouse is. However, it seems pygame or move_ip only work with integers. I can click between what would be 1.00000001 and 1.9999999 and the ball will shoot in the exact spot, being 1 (in reference to the x coordinate). This is bad for my game. Is there a solution to this so I can get my objects to move very precisely?

EDIT: I realized I pasted in the wrong code. `self.rect.center = (c[0]+x, c[1]+y)` is where `self.rect.move_ip(x, y)` should be. Both methods yield the same result, however.

Comment: I've never worked with pygame before, but I'm confused about what `move_ip()` is and does. In your code sample you have a function called `move()`, what's the difference between that and `move_ip()`?

Comment: @Dennis Ah, I copied the wrong version. `self.rect.center = (c[0]+x, c[1]+y)` would normally be `self.rect.move_ip(x, y)` I tried just updating the rect.center in order to do what Amber suggested below, but both methods have the same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep track of your own positions using precise `float` values, and then instead of incrementally moving your `Rect`s from frame to frame, just place them at their proper (integer-ized) positions each frame. That way you don't suffer from the sum of each frame's rounding error, but instead only have a single rounding involved at any given time.

Comment: Curious how that differs from my example above? How would I accomplish that if it does differ.

Comment: In your example, you're calculating the movement based on `time_passed`, which I'm assuming is time since the last frame. In other words, you're computing a change in position. What I'm saying is, don't compute just a change in position - also compute a *final* position, and store that *separately* from the `Rect`. Every time you write to the `Rect` object, it's throwing away the decimal portion.